# Anyone using WP-CodeBox 1.4 with Wordpress 2.8.6

Tags: wordpress

Over the last year or so I tried using WP-CodeBox for a syntax highlighting tool. I downloaded a couple of versions and tried them with a few versions of WordPress. I have never been able to get CodeBox to work. Anyone suggestions? Anyone using this combination or have a similiar story? What did you do?

I like the features it offers like links to download files, line numbering, copy to clipboard, and expand/collapse of the code box. If there is another tool that offers these features, let me know.

WP-CodeBox - http://www.ericbess.com/ericblog/2008/03/03/wp-codebox/

I'd prefer to use CodeBox but if I can't make it work, I need to use something else. I cannot change the version of WordPress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using it successfully on my blog. I just upgraded to 1.4 which appears to have broken a few things so I downgraded back to 1.3.3. I'm currently using 1.3.3 with WP 2.8.6 & just upgraded to 2.9. Haven't had any problems with the 1.3.3 version. Just noticed on Eric's site that he recently released 1.4.1. Haven't tried it yet though.

[lamolabs blog](http://www.lamolabs.org/blog/) is my blog. I use the WP-Codebox all over the site without any issues.

Answer (score 1):

I use it with WP 2.8.4 in production site and 2.8.6 at home, both working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've just installed on the same version and it's not working properly. It displays the code, but the collpase bar, images and line numbers don't appear. I'm going to have to hunt around for something else.